# Application flashes and crash immediately after opening in latest ios

Tags: ios, ios10, crash

This is very wired, after new ios release my app is crashing immediately after opening. No crash log no clues, nothing.

If anyone know about this issue and fixed before, please help.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Run the app in the debugger. Any output in the console?

Comment: If you can't connect the debugger. Do you have looked into the crash logs in  Xcode (see _Window_ | _Devices_)?

Comment: Check your View connection, if you work on storyboard then check Option like:-- View Controller  option n select "IS INITIAL VIEW CONTROLLER" option n check once

Comment: It's coming randomly in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Check your View connection, if you work on storyboard then check Option like:-- View Controller option n select "IS INITIAL VIEW CONTROLLER" option n check once